# AttributeError: 'AuthorizedSession' object has no attribute 'configure_mtls_channel'

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I was orchestrating two dataflow job with cloud composer and it was working fine for month. Suddenly the two jobs stopped working with the following error message:

> in download_blob File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py",
> line 399, in get_bucket retry=retry, File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py",
> line 1002, in reload retry=retry, File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_helpers.py",
> line 225, in reload retry=retry, File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_http.py",
> line 63, in api_request return call() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py",
> line 286, in retry_wrapped_func on_error=on_error, File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py",
> line 184, in retry_target return target() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line
> 479, in api_request timeout=timeout, File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line
> 337, in _make_request method, url, headers, data, target_object,
> timeout=timeout File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line
> 374, in _do_request return self.http.request( File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line
> 157, in http return self._client._http File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line
> 187, in _http
> self._http_internal.configure_mtls_channel(self._client_cert_source)
> AttributeError: 'AuthorizedSession' object has no attribute
> 'configure_mtls_channel'

In the jobs I download a file from google cloud storage with the storage client. I assumed it was because of some dependencies issues. In the composer environment I installed google-cloud-storage without specifying a version. I tried specifying different versions of the package but nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you were able to debug this issue? so I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I pinned google-cloud-core to 1.5.0 as you suggest and it solved the problem. And it was a batch job. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be related to this [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/513).

Try [pinning google-cloud-core to 1.5.0](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/513#issuecomment-775316656), then I highly recommend for you to [Drain](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/stopping-a-pipeline#drain) your jobs once you get them back to work (assuming they have streaming jobs).

Comment: @ShaqL If you accept this please up-vote the thread :)